# Why did Saruman try to "turn" Gandalf and thus reveal he's evil?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

Up until Saruman imprisoned Gandalf in Orthanc, everyone (except Sauron, I guess) seems to have believed that Saruman was on the side of good - while his influence was growing in Rohan. It seems like this situation, where he was a known ally, head of the White Council, and acknowledged greatest expert on the Rings -- but secretly had his influence working in Rohan -- would give him a much better chance of getting the Ring himself than being the enemy of both Gandalf and Rohan.

So why did he ask Gandalf to turn evil, vs. pretending to still be good and (once Gandalf asked him about Bilbo/Frodo's Ring) setting up a version of the 'Council of Elrond' where he could name himself as one of those responsible for destroying the ring, thus allowing him to claim it himself?

Did he really believe Gandalf would go over to his side?

Was it just that he didn't think he could hide his Orcs?

Or was it due to Sauron's influence on him through the Palantir making him less rational?

Comment: We can guess, but I don't think there's anything in the books to support such speculations. So this is probably not a good question for this site.

Comment: Arrogance, I'd say. Something along the lines of "If I, Saruman the Wise, can be corrupted, then why not that old fool Gandalf?"

Comment: More like, "Arrogance. I, Saruman the Wise, am the wisest person in Middle Earth. Every team I am on is a winning team. Gandalf knows this and is smart enough to join me."

Comment: Perhaps he thought Gandalf suspected as much and it wouldn't be long before the orcs were discovered and the trees all being removed. Maybe Saruman was giving one last chance to join him before killing him, but he underestimated how much Gandalf has grown in cunning and valor.

Comment: Gandalf says that something always held him back from mentioning Bilbo's ring to Saruman, so there never was and would never be a time when "Gandalf asked him about Bilbo/Frodo's Ring". And no one would believe that Saruman was "one of those responsible for destroying the ring": they all knew he wasn't around the last time the ring had been seen, and he himself had already said it wasn't destroyed but rolled out to sea. The question assumes things that contradict the book.

Comment: @Matt Gutting  I think that cometary orbit meant that Saruman would get himself appointed to the Fellowship of the Ring, with the responsibility of destroying the ring in the future, and take advantage of beig with Frodo on the quest to take the ring for himself.  Not tht Saruman would claim to have destroyed the ring in the past.

Comment: @M.A.Golding exactly. Saruman was the White Council's chief expert on Ring lore, so he would seem an obvious member of whatever version of the Council of Elrond would have happened if Gandalf hadn't been delayed by being imprisoned by Saruman, and could probably name himself as a member of the Fellowship(-equivalent).

Comment: @MattGutting hmm, maybe Gandalf would not have... but I had thought that was why Gandalf visited Saruman, and if Saruman had not started to talk like an evil guy Gandalf would have told him more.  But surely he would have been called to whatever version of the Council of Elrond would have happened, at least?

Comment: Gandalf didn't visit Saruman to ask about the ring - he specifically says that something told him not to mention it. He went because Radagast told him Saruman wanted to talk to him and because he wanted help against the Nazgûl. And Saruman had no idea in July that Frodo was going to try for Rivendell, much less that Elrond would hold a council to see what to do with the Ring.

Comment: @MattGutting ok, good point. I agree that the Council of Elrond specifically wasn't planned. I guess a better phrasing would be that if Saruman was still considered an ally of Rohan and Gondor and a member in good standing (and head!) of the White Council, as the Council's primary expert on the Rings, if it were found by the good side he would be likely to be consulted on how to safely contain/destroy/otherwise deal with it... which would give him a very good chance to obtain it for himself.

Comment: There was no preconceived plan to form a Fellowship of the Ring. That fell out as a result of the unplanned, serendipitous convergence of interested parties in Rivendell at the time Frodo arrived with the Ring. Saruman simply thought he could get Gandalf to reveal the location of the Ring.

Comment: Because he's a schmuck

Comment: It is 40 years since I last read LotR, but I believe it is mentioned that Saruman gazed too much into his palantir, which fed him false images of Sauron's forces being to strong to overcome, even by the full forces of Elves and Men. He thus decided that his best chance was to side with the winner and become a trusted lieutenant of Sauron. "Better to serve in Hell than to die for Heaven", I guess.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen While Sauron did use the Palantiri to mislead and it was a factor in Saruman turning, the strength of Sauron’s forces and the hopelessness of beating him in war was not false.  It was a point repeated in the books, including by people who never touched a Palantir.  The ring was sent on such a seemingly hopeless journey precisely because there was no other way to beat Sauron.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tolkien rarely gives us a direct insight into the bad guys' thinking, so it's difficult to give a definitive answer. However, we do know that there was mutual suspicion between Gandalf and Saruman. In the Shadow of the Past, Gandalf tells Frodo that 'something' held him back from discussing the ring with Saruman. Part (iii) of The Hunt for the Ring (Unfinished Tales) suggests that Gandalf's suspicion dated back to at least TA2851. At the time of their meeting in Isengard (TA3018), Saruman had guessed that Gandalf knew the location of the ring, and had withheld this information. Saruman also realised that he needed to lure Gandalf to Isengard on false pretenses (hence the trick involving Radagast). With this in mind, what convincing lies could Saruman have told? Suggesting a meeting of the White Council to decide on a course of action would be reasonable, but Rivendell would be the natural location for this - it's easier for the ring-bearer to reach, much further from Mordor than Isengard and is also the home of Middle-earth's greatest lore-master. 'Naming himself as one of those responsible for destroying the ring' doesn't make sense at this point. The plan to destroy the ring hadn't been formed; it was only reached after a long discussion in which all other courses of action were ruled out. On the other hand, plans such as allying with Sauron or seizing the ring for themselves (actually himself) would seem entirely natural to Saruman since he was under the influence of Sauron. It's likely he thought they would seem reasonable to Gandalf as well.

Comment: Good answer, but partial. I think you need add Saruman's arrogance into mix as well as his palantir-fueled perception that the Good Guys were doomed. His arrogance led him to think he could manipulate Gandalf and pick up a strong subordinate since his plan was to be the power behind Sauron's throne and perhaps ultimately to sit there himself.